# Does an Android SQLite database persist after switching the device off?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to develop an Android app. I would like to get the input from user and store it in the phone's database.

My data should be retained in the phone even if the phone gets switched off. Is this possible using an SQLite database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space your data requires

Your data storage options are the following:

Shared Preferences
Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.

Internal Storage
Store private data on the device memory.

External Storage
Store public data on the shared external storage.

SQLite Databases
Store structured data in a private database.

Comment: My app deals with saving and retrieving of structured data. But I heard that data is not persistent with sqlite database.

Comment: it will be persistent that what i have answered

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to get the input from user and store it in the phone
>   database(for which sqlite is used). I would like to know , if I can
>   prefer to build my app using sqlite database. My data should be
>   retained in the phone even if the phone gets switched off. Is it
>   possible using sqlite database?

**Yes** you can Use sqlite Database.

But, if you have data like one or two String then you should Go with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Hope it Will Help.

Answer (score 1):

It's very much possible. But most likely overkill as well.

Have you tried SharedPreferences? They are persisted even when your application closes or the phone is switched off.

An example:

For saving preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YourAppPreferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putInt("yourvalue", 14);
editor.putString("name", "John");
e.commit();
```

And this is how you retrieve them:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YourAppPreferences", 0);
preferences .getInt("yourvalue", 0)
```

The second parameter in `getInt` is the `default value` in case it is not set.

Comment: Thanks!! I cannot opt for SharedPreferences except using sqlite.

Comment: Okay, if you think a SqlLite Db will be your best option, go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

**For your inspiration!**

The most powerful
method for local storage is with SQLite databases. Each application is equipped with
its own SQLite database, which is accessible by any class in the application, but not
by any outside applications. Before moving on to complex queries or snippets of
code, let me just give a quick summary of what SQLite databases are.
SQL (Structured Query Language) is a programming language designed especially
for managing data in relational databases. Relational databases allow you to submit
insert, delete, update, and get queries, while also allowing you to create and modify
schemas (more simply thought of as tables). SQLite then is simply a scaled-down
version of MySQL, PostgreSQL, and other popular database systems. It is entirely
self-contained and server-less, while still being transactional and still using the
standard SQL language for executing queries. Because of how it's self-contained
and executable, it is extremely efficient, flexible, and accessible by a wide variety
of programming languages across a wide variety of platforms (including our very
own Android platform).

Comment: For further reading: [link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite Database commonly used to persist the data in most Android applications.

Sqlite file is created in your package folder.

To Backup Sqlite file

1.copy the Sqlite file to your sdcard (No Network connection needed)
2.Sync your Sqlite file to google Drive(Network connection needed)

Sample URL:
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android

Content Provider Advantages Over Sqlite Database

1.Advantage of Loaders (Loaded Latest data)

2.Easy to sync data

3.share data to other applications

Sqlite data is persisted after application close and even phone switch off.