# Database is locked in Azure Django

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an **App service** running **django app** on free service on **linux**.

it is resetting my `db.sqlite3` file again and again and i can not afford to use **postgresql** as it is not in free services (I don't have azure free credit).

How can i make `db.sqlite3` file **persistent**?

Things I have tried:

1. tried adding `db.sqlite3` in `/home/site/wwwroot/`  but django is showing that **database is locked**.
2. created `dbfiles` directory in `/tmp` folder and added `db.sqlite3` in `/tmp/dbfiles`  but django is showing that **unable to open database file**.

Comment: You might have  opened  the database from SQLite Browser. Close it and check once.

Comment: SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can't support a high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.

Comment: You can solve it by: Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived. Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option

Comment: To make **db.sqlite3** file **persistent**  refer [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377686) and [Persist data with SQLite](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Persisting-Data-to-the-Device)

Comment: My app is running perfectly when it is on the same directory as code.

Comment: my app is only open in django and nowhere else. is there any other database i can use for free?

Comment: Please refer [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)